# Example how to cancel a libCurl request

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

I ask me, how I can cancel an curl request:

```
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

Answer (score 10):

Use [CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTPROGRESSFUNCTION) callback and return non-zero to abort when you decide to. Maybe you could use some other more appropriate callbacks depending on your requirements.

Comment: This only works if data is being transferred while curl is blocked waiting it will not call this function thus you won't be able to cancel.

Comment: @Eelke Do you mean blocked on a socket? In this case it's not an issue with curl itself, but underlying OS socket API.

Comment: No it is the way `curl_easy_perform` works it uses blocking socket io and only calls the progress callback when it is receiving data. Depending on the kind of operation you are doing there can be a period of time where there is not going any data over the line because the other side is doing internal processing or just very slow responding. To solve for that situation you have to use the curls multi api which is select/poll based.

Comment: @kan It says OBSOLETE. Also I think the right answer may be using the cURL multi API.

Comment: @MelroyvandenBerg It's obsolete by a `CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION` which has the very same logic, but using integers instead of `double` numbers for exact precision. The multi-api is more flexible, but harder to use... So, the choice is yours.

Answer (score 7):

You also have the option to use curl_multi_remove_handle. As stated in the offical curl documentation:

"Removing an easy handle while being used is perfectly legal and will effectively halt the transfer in progress involving that easy handle. All other easy handles and transfers will remain unaffected."

c.f.
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_remove_handle.html

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example of this being done? A link to the documentation you're quoting would also be useful.

Comment: `curl_multi_remove_handle` can only be used when you are using the multi interface! It cannot be used with `curl_easy_perform` you need to call `curl_multi_add_handle` instead.

Comment: maybe then you need to use the multi-handle mode to actually manage aborting request properly without using timeout options or the likes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily interrupt a running function from within C; you'll need to use signals. Typing Ctrl+C at your program should terminate the cURL call, but also kills your process by default. To send a signal programmatically, you'll need a separate threads or process to do so.

Depending on what problem you're trying to solve, you may want to set [`CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTTIMEOUT) with [`curl_easy_setopt`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html).

Comment: This is just not true, you can use the cURL multi API instead . Which is select/poll based.

Answer (score -4):

`curl_easy_cleanup` is your friend here I guess.